# Retrieve the week number from a date

Tags: c#, date, week-number

I am using the following method to retrieve the week.

```
public int GetWeek(DateTime date)
{
    var day = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(date);
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.AddDays(4 - (day == 0 ? 7 : day)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);            
}
```

If the week number is between 0 to 9, it should return 00 - 09 as the week number.
How can I do it?

Comment: `00` and `09` sound more like string sthan numbers to me...

Comment: This question is unrelated to weeks (in particular, it is not about *retrieving* the week number), or any thing related to dates, for that matter. It is a duplicate of the linked question about number formatting. That said, a *formatted* number is a `string`, not an `int` any more.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: Please read the question. The OP is *not* asking about how to find out or compute a week number.

Comment: @   O. R. Mapper :  see my answer

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: There does not seem to be any answer written by you on the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that, as you are looking for a leading zero, you are looking to format these numbers.

If so, simply use int.ToString() to format your GetWeek method:

```
 public int GetWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        var day = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(date);
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.AddDays(4 - (day == 0 ? 7 : day)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);            
    }

public string GetWeekFormatted(DateTime date)
{
    return GetWeek(date).ToString("00");
}
```